# URL manager issue in yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

This is my backend url : `http://localhost/game_website_new/phase1/admin/` and its working fine but,

Now I have a `forum` folder in my application directory and it will accessible in frontend like this : `http://localhost/game_website_new/phase1/forum` Working.

But I want to use forum in backend like this : `http://localhost/game_website_new/phase1/admin/forum` and this is not working.

below is my site `.htaccess` file

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin(.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by going to
`config` (if you use advanced app in will be `common/config`) folder of your app and open `web.php` or `main.php` there you will see something like this.

```
$config = [
      'urlManager' => [
      //some configs here
      ],
```

search for 'urlManager' to find your config file.

read some doc's on it http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

I think it you situation this should work

```
$config = [
    'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'enableStrictParsing' => false,
                'rules' => [
                    //you can use regexp in parameters
                    'your/new/url/<parameterId:\d+>' => 'old/url', // old url will match something like moduleIfYouHaveOne/YourController/YourAction
                    'phase1/admin/forum' => 'phase1/forum',
                ],
```